# Prevent two players from being matched twice in Swiss Style Tournament

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, sorting

I am currently trying to design a simple [Swiss Style Tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss-system_tournament) generator, as a way to play around with jquery and satisfy my own curiosity. However I have hit a bit of a roadblock.

I have already built an algorithm that sorts the players at end of round based on number of wins, draws and losses, but I need some way to prevent a the players being matched with the same opponent twice.

Currently the players are stored in an array with even players matching off with odd players (eg, `playersarray[0]` vs `playersarray[1]`, `playersarray[2]`vs`playersarray[3]` etc.). Each player in the array is and object with the properties `name`, `win`, `draw`, `loss`, `lostGame` (used for determining who lost, both lost is draw), and `hasPlayed` (which stores who they have already been matched with by name).

Here is my sorting algorthim as it stands now:

```
//---SORTING ARRAYS----
//Danish Style (Players can play the same Player twice)
//Sort loss to bottom
playersArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseFloat(a.loss) - parseFloat(b.loss);    
});
//Sort Draw to top
playersArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseFloat(b.draw) - parseFloat(a.draw);    
});
//Sort with wins on top
playersArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseFloat(b.win) - parseFloat(a.win);    
});
//Swiss Style (make it so Players can't play the same opponet twice)
for(var j = 0; j < playersArray.length; j +=2){
    if($.inArray(playersArray[j].name, playersArray[j+1].haveplayed) != -1){
        var tempI = playersArray[j];
        playersArray[j] = playersArray[j-1];
        playersArray[j-1] = tempI;
        console.log("Matched!");

    }
}
```

My solution right now is pretty bad as it just swaps the player up one, and dosen't work if the position 0 and 1 players match.

Any insight into how I might be able to solve this problem would be appreciated as it seems to be quite the brain twister to me.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you just need to replace u're "if" to a "while"  that cycles through all players until there is no "match". Does it makes sense?

Comment: It seems a little hamfisted, as it would just shift the players up until they are all at the top. I would also need to put in something that catches it if there isn't a solution, otherwise it will just hang. I am pretty sure a more elegant solution is possible as there is some standalone (not webpage) software that builds Swiss Style tournaments, I just don't know how to get a look at its sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't necessarily compare win/draw/loss counts but a general score:

Win +1, Draw +0, Loss -1

A general score has also the benefit to give you an easier time when checking for the "close score" rule:

> In subsequent rounds, each competitor faces an opponent with the same, or almost the same, cumulative score.

Next, I'ld break the code up a bit - but that's a personal preference. It's always nice if you have a fast little algorythm, but it can hurt readability and complicate things in the long run. Why don't you just store past matchups in the Player instance, and check if two players already had a matchup (even storing the result)?

I wrote a little example that breaks it up into a bit clearer components (Matches and Players). Of course this can be further optimized and shortened, but it's mainly written out in this way to give you a clear oerview of every step. It's based on the rules on the wiki page provided.

https://jsfiddle.net/ovkktbg6/5/

```
// settings
var MAX_SCORE_DIFFERENCE = 2;

// match
function Match(player1, player2, result) {
    this.player1 = player1
    this.player2 = player2

    // player1 [won/draw/lost] against player2
    this.result = result

    // give each player the match results
    this.player1.addMatch(this)
    this.player2.addMatch(this)

    console.log(player1.name, result == Match.RESULT_WIN ? 'won' : ( result == Match.RESULT_LOSS ? 'lost' : 'draw' ), 'against', player2.name, '-', player1.score, ':', player2.score)
}

// possible results
Match.RESULT_WIN  = 1
Match.RESULT_DRAW = 0
Match.RESULT_LOSS = -1

Match.randomResult = function() {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * (Match.RESULT_WIN - Match.RESULT_LOSS + 1) ) + Match.RESULT_LOSS;
}

// player
function Player(name) {
    this.name    = name // just to have any identification
    this.score   = 0
    this.wins    = 0
    this.losses  = 0
    this.draws   = 0
    this.matches = []
}

Player.prototype.addMatch = function( match ) {
    this.matches.push(match)

    if( match.result == Match.RESULT_DRAW ) {
        this.draws++;
    } else {

        // check if the first player is this one
        if( match.player1 == this ) {

            // this player1 has WON against player2
            if(match.result == Match.RESULT_WIN) {
                this.wins++;
                this.score++;
            } else {
                this.wins--;
                this.score--;
            }

        // this player is player2
        } else {

            // player1 has LOST against this player2
            if(match.result == Match.RESULT_LOSS) {
                this.wins++;
                this.score++;
            } else {
                this.wins--;
                this.score--;
            }
        }
    }
}

Player.prototype.hasPlayedAgainst = function( player ) {

    // a player canot play against him/herself
    if( this == player ) return false;

    // check the other matches
    for( var i = 0; i < this.matches.length; i++ ) {
        var match = this.matches[i]

        if( match.player1 == player || match.player2 == player) return true; 
    }

    return false;
}

// example
var playerList = []

playerList.push( new Player('Alex') )
playerList.push( new Player('Bob') )
playerList.push( new Player('Charles') )
playerList.push( new Player('David') )
playerList.push( new Player('Erik') )
playerList.push( new Player('Franz') )
playerList.push( new Player('Georg') )
playerList.push( new Player('Hans') )
playerList.push( new Player('Ian') )
playerList.push( new Player('Jacob') )
playerList.push( new Player('Karl') )
playerList.push( new Player('Lars') )
playerList.push( new Player('Marco') )

// if the matchups should be random each time, the playerList can be:
// randomly ordered once, here - the tournament will have random matchups
// or randomly ordered inside the while() loop. Every tournament round will have random matchups then

// play through the tournament
// pick every player in the playerList and match them against every other player
var round         = 0
var matchPossible = true

while( matchPossible ) {

    // this flag is set to true if there was a match
    // if no match was played, that means that the tournament is over, since every player already competed against each other or there are no similar enough scores to play
    matchPossible = false;

    // this loop goes through the whole player list the first time, picking player1
    for( var i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++ ) {
        var player1 = playerList[i];

        // exclude players who already played this round
        if( player1.matches.length > round ) {
            continue;
        }

        // this loop goes through the whole player list once more, picking player2
        // the two loops match every player against every player, skipping their match with the conditions below
        for( var ii = 0; ii < playerList.length; ii++ ) {
            var player2 = playerList[ii];

            // do not play against him/herself
            if( player1 == player2 ) {
                continue;
            }

            // exclude players who already played this round
            if( player2.matches.length > round ) {
                continue;
            }

            // the two already faced each other
            if( player1.hasPlayedAgainst( player2 ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            // their scores are too far apart
            if( Math.abs( player1.score - player2.score ) > MAX_SCORE_DIFFERENCE ) {
                continue;
            }

            // there was a match!
            matchPossible = true

            // if we get here, the players should face each other
            new Match( player1, player2, Match.randomResult() );

            // break out, let the next players have a match
            break;
        }
    }

    // start the next round
    round++;
}

// the tournament ended - let's rank them.
playerList.sort( function( player1, player2 ) {
    return player2.score - player1.score;
} ) 

// print the results
console.log('-----')

for( var i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++ ) {
    var player = playerList[i];

    console.log('Rank', i + 1, ':', player.name, 'with', player.score, 'points');
}
```

**Edit:** Another advantage of breaking it up like this is that you don't have to worry too much about clever sorting algorithms and stuff like that - every component just does it's job according to the given rules, and in the end you evaluate the results.

It's not intensively tested, so it's quite possible that it still has some hidden bugs, but generaly it should work fine according to the few tests I did.

**Edit:** As requested, I'll try to explain the loop a bit further. The two `for()` loops basically do nothing else than to first pick player1, and then match player1 to every player in the playerList (each called player2). When the current player1 was matched against each player2, the next player1 is selected.

Let's say we have Alex as player1:

```
Alex (player1) is matched against Alex (player2) [no match - same player]
Alex (player1) is matched against Bob (player2) [no match - already had a match]
Alex (player1) is matched against Charles (player2) - they have a match!
Now the nested `for( var ii )` loop is broken with `break;`, and Alex (player1) is done for the moment. We pick the next player in the playerList:
Bob (player1) is matched against Alex (player2) [no match - already had a match]
Bob (player1) is matched against Bob (player2) [no match - same player]
Bob (player1) is matched against Charles (player2) [no match - charles already had a match this round]
Bob (player1) is matched against David (player2) - they have a match!
Now the nested `for( var ii)` loop breaks a second time, and we continue with Charles
Charles (player1) is matched against Alex (player2) [no match - already had a match]
etc...
```

Meanwhile, the `while( ... )` loop goes through each round of the tournament: Each round, all players are checked against each other, until we reach a point where no player is allowed to play against any other player. The tournament is over at that point, and we can sort the playerList according to the scores.

**Edit (2):** just to visualize my explanation with the `continue` and `break` keywords a bit better, since it's difficult to do in comment: (keep in mind, this is just pseudo-code for presentation purposes.)

**Continue**

```
for( loop A ) {
    for( loop B ) {
         continue; // just skip to the end of loop B, and go through loop B again!

         ... this stuff is skipped by continue ...

         END OF LOOP <- continue gets us here! loop A is unaffected
    }
}
```

**Break**

```
for( loop A ) {
    for( loop B ) {
         break; // completly jump out of loop B!

         ... this stuff is skipped by break ...
    }
    <- break gets us here! loop B is broken out of, we just continue with the code in loop A

    ... stuff that is NOT skipped by break! ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the well written Answer, I am still new to JavaScript so it takes me time to read through code to determine what is going on. Let me see if I understand correctly. You have created an object called `Match` that stores the result of a player playing against their opponent as well as both of their names. That object in turn is stored inside the `Player` obj which is stored in the `playerList`. The meat of the sorting is done from line 103 down, where you continually check different options until it can't match, then stop. It is here in the nested for loops that I get a little lost.

Comment: @Malco Yes, partially - I basically broke up the whole game logic into Match and Player. And Match doesn't store the players names, but the Player object instances. What happens in the nested loop: First, it goes through each player ( var i ), and then goes to each player again (var ii), matching each player with each other, every round. The while(...) loop goes through every single round, repeating the checks until no possible matchup remains. That part is basically the tournament, and has nothing to do with the sorting yet. I'll edit my answer to try and better explain what's going on ;)

Comment: Ahh I am starting to get it. I am actually going through it right now and assimilating it into my project. I didn't think to nest the loops, but that is doing exactly what I needed, comparing one person to all the rest. And just for clarity, `continue` breaks out of the for loop and starts over again from the top incrementing`i` or `ii` by 1 correct?

Comment: @Malco the keyword `continue` just skips to the end of the current loop, while the keyword `break` breaks out of the current loop. If you are in the loop `for( var ii ... )` and `continue`, it just basically increments `ii`, and goes through `for( var ii ...)` again, whitout touching `for( var i ... )`. With `break`, `for(var ii ...)` is completly interrupted, and the code just continues where the loop ends at `}` - in this case, it just increments `for (var i ...)` - I updated my answer to clarify your last questions a bit, but I'll add this one as well.

Comment: @Malco please see my second Edit (2) for a clearer explanation ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch things are clicking together now. I know the logic works so the only thing left is to implement it into my project. Thanks again for clarifying you have been a big help.

Comment: I think your matching algorithm has a crucial issue (though not verified yet) in that for later rounds it can happen that there are players who have no possible opponent left, while the top scoring players have already been assigned matches. There needs to be some backtracking logic.